# Prove that a sequence of recursive functions $\,f_n(x)$ cannot converge pointwise to $\,f(x)$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Given a recursive sequence $\,f_n(x) :[0,1] \to \mathbb R$, $x \in [0,1]$, where
$$\begin{align*}
f_1(x) &= x, \\[6pt]
f_n(x) &= \frac{2x\,f_{n-1}(x)}{n!}
\end{align*}$$
I have proven that the sequence is non-negative and non-increasing, but cannot prove that its pointwise convergent. I'm not even sure if it is pointwise convergent! Im having trouble defining an $N(x,\epsilon)$ to use for the Cauchy definition for a convergent sequence. The recursion is really throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** for any $x\in[0,1]$,

Using a recursion $$
\begin {cases}
f_1(x) = 1 =: u_1 \\
f_{n+1}(x) = \frac{2}{n!}f_n(x) \le 
\frac{2}{n!}u_n =:  u_{n+1} 
\end {cases}
$$

so it is enough to prove that $u_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is given that $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!}2x f_{n-1}(x)$. In particular, for every $x\in[0,1]$ and $n\geq3$:
$$0\leq f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!}2x f_{n-1}(x)\leq\frac{1}{n!}2 f_{n-1}(x)\leq\frac{1}{2}f_{n-1}(x)$$

Suppose that $f_3(x)\leq M$ for every $x\in[0,1]$. Then $f_{3+k}(x)\leq \frac{M}{2^k}$. Do you understand that this implies uniform convergence?

Comment: yes i can see that for f3+k(x) <= M/2^k as k ---> infinity, f---> zero, but how did you get M/2^k ? How did you decide on that bound?

Comment: @stensoj3
$$x\leq 1$$ and conclude